# SSRS sparkline with small difference in values

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have created a sparkline in SSRS. Since the values are small i get a straight line graph How do i improve the sensitivity of the graph.

the difference is like for every month
60.06
60.40
60.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the Sparkline **Vertical Axis Properties**.

Testing with data like yours and a simple Tablix/Sparkline I get results similar to yours:

[image]

[image]

Opening the **Vertical Axis Properties** I can see `Always include zero` is checked by default:

[image]

Unchecking this option has a major effect on the sparkline:

[image]

So this is one way of doing it. Other than that changing the `Minimum` and `Maximum` values here will also have an effect - you just need to play around and find the right combination for you.

Comment: I unchecked the always include 0 , but did not find any difference. The graph is still a straight line. And also i tried changes the min and max to 50 to 70. and i could not see the graph. Do u know whow do i set the interval ? like vertical interval bar with intervels like 60.0, 60.1,60.2,60.3 ...

Comment: I don't think you can set intervals on a sparkline since there aren't any actual grid lines or similar. If the options in the properties aren't helping then perhaps other data in the tablix is affecting that particular group?

Comment: Wel did some work around and some how showed some difference... Thanks for the help